# FunctionCompile returns Part::partd: Part specification 151345[[1]] is longer than depth of object

Tags: compile

Today, I install mathematica 12.3 on my computer(windows), then I run the FunctionCompile code

```
cf = FunctionCompile[Function[Typed[arg, "MachineInteger"], arg + 1]]
```

but it goes wrong, and return the information

```
Part::partd: Part specification 151345[[1]] is longer than depth of object
```

I test on my another computer, FunctionCompile works well, so what's happening here?

Comment: Works fine for me (Windows 10, 12.3)

Comment: Works for me, try a new kernel.